# Every complex vector bundle over the circle is trivial

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $E \rightarrow S^1$ be a smooth complex vector bundle over $S^1$ (here complex means that the fibers have a vector space structure over $\mathbb{C}$).

Is it true that $E$ is necessarily trivial?

If so, what is the simplest proof?

Comment: $\pi_1 BU(n) = \pi_0 U(n) = 0$.

Comment: @MikeMiller, maybe an explanation in plain (mathematical) English would be better?

Answer (score 2):

A complex vector bundle over $S^1$ pulls back to a trivial vector bundle under the quotient map $[0,1]\to S^1$. A choice of such trivialization gives us an automorphism of the fiber $E_1$, since it has two different preimages in $[0,1]$. Changing the rivialization amounts to changing this automorphism by a homotopy. Since every two complex invertible matrices are attached by a path of such matrices, we may correct the trivialization such that the corresponding automorphism is te identity. Then, the trivialization descends to $S^1$.